# Create another root account with ubuntu

Tags: root, adduser

It is indicated that on the manual of **adduser** we can do :

```
sudo useradd -ou 0 anotherroot
```

Where anotherroot is the name of **the new root account.**

**The link of adduser manual :** https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd

But on ubuntu 16.10 when you open manual of useradd in terminal there is no option like :

```
-o, --non-unique
```

**It's possible to create a new root account with Ubuntu 16.10 ?**

**EDIT 1 :**

I would like to create a root account that is independent of the basic root account :

```
sanbox@sanbox-virtual-machine:~$ su root
Password: 
root@sanbox-virtual-machine:/home/sanbox#
```

I have assigned a new account named john to root :

```
sudo useradd -ou 0 john
```

but when i try :

```
su john
Password: 
root@sanbox-virtual-machine:/home/sanbox#
```

I don't want that, i want if you do `su john`

```
Password: 
john@sanbox-virtual-machine:/home/sanbox#
```

**where john is another root account**

Comment: What another root account means?

Comment: if you do : su root, you will be redirected to root account like : root@machine ; i want to create an user with root privileges

Comment: I think you may wish to reconsider doing this - this opens you up to a whole new vector of attacks if someone gets to your system, or if the system has SSH enabled on it.

Comment: @ThomasWard it's a virtual machine for learn linux

Comment: And who will be owner of system files and processes and so on?

Answer (score 2):

`useradd` and `adduser` are two different programs. `useradd` is a low-level utility, while (on Debian and operating systems derived from Debian) for most practical purposes one should use `adduser` instead. You are reading two different manuals. Ubuntu `useradd` does have the `-o` option, which allows adding aliases for existing accounts. Anyway, adding an alias for root is bad idea.

Comment: it's just for learning more about root account

Comment: i would like to create a root account like : newroot@virtual-machine

Comment: but not with sudoers

Answer (score 0):

In the virtual machine do this:

1. Log in to your virtual machine.
2. Use the adduser command to add a new user to your virtual machine. Be sure to replace  username with the user that you want to create.

   - `sudo adduser john`
3. Use the usermod command to add the user to the sudo group.

   - `sudo usermod -aG sudo john`
4. Test sudo access on new user account.

   - `su - john`

**Note:** All this is done in the *virtual machine*.

Answer (score 0):

You can create user accounts with the same UID, but UIDs are *expected* to be unique, so there's no guarantee that applications will behave the way you expect them to.

> I have assigned a new account named john to root :
>
> ```
> sudo useradd -ou 0 john
> ```
>
> but when i try :
>
> ```
> su john
> Password: 
> root@sanbox-virtual-machine:/home/sanbox#
> ```
>
> I don't want that, i want if you do
>
> ```
> su john
> Password: 
> john@sanbox-virtual-machine:/home/sanbox#
> ```

You can try moving `john`'s `/etc/passwd` entry to be above root's, but then applications that try to run as `root` will face problems.

Applications rely on unique user IDs. Don't make duplicate UIDs and expect anything to have sane behaviour.